# An error occurred while calling o898.save. Exception encountered in Azure Synapse Analytics connector code

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-databricks

```
def synapsedump(targetmount,targetfolder,table,df):
  dbutils.fs.rm("/mnt/tmp", recurse=True)
  df.createOrReplaceTempView(table)
  spark.conf.set("spark.databricks.sqldw.writeSemantics", "copy")
  schema = "Amazon"
  schematable = schema + "." + table
  df = spark.sql("select * from " + table) 
  print(df.count())
  
  df.write \
  .format("com.databricks.spark.sqldw") \
  .option("url", sqlconnectionstring ) \
  .option("forwardSparkAzureStorageCredentials", "true") \
  .option("dbTable", schematable) \
  .option("tableOptions", "distribution=hash(HashSha2)") \
  .option("maxStrLength", "4000") \
  .option("tempDir", sqltempdir) \
  .mode("append") \
  .save()
  df.write.mode("append").parquet(targetmount + targetfolder + table)
```

Above is my write function that I am using to write to multiple tables in synapse in the same notebook.

This code used to work perfectly fine earlier however it has for some reason started to throw the below error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o898.save.
: com.databricks.spark.sqldw.SqlDWConnectorException: Exception encountered in Azure Synapse Analytics connector code.
    at com.databricks.spark.sqldw.Utils$.wrapExceptions(Utils.scala:444)
    at com.databricks.spark.sqldw.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$execute$1(SparkPlan.scala:200)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$3(SparkPlan.scala:252)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:248)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:158)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:157)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.$anonfun$runCommand$1(DataFrameWriter.scala:999)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$5(SQLExecution.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:249)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$1(SQLExecution.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:845)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withCustomExecutionEnv(SQLExecution.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:199)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:999)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:437)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:421)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:380)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:295)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unexpected version returned: Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8 
    Jun 24 2021 23:23:51 
    Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation

Make sure your JDBC url includes a "database=<DataWareHouseName>" option and that
it points to a valid Azure Synapse SQL Analytics (Azure SQL Data Warehouse) name.
This connector cannot be used for interacting with any other systems (e.g. Azure
SQL Databases).
               
    at com.databricks.spark.sqldw.DefaultSource.$anonfun$validateJdbcConnection$2(DefaultSource.scala:146)
    at com.databricks.spark.sqldw.DefaultSource.$anonfun$validateJdbcConnection$2$adapted(DefaultSource.scala:140)
    at com.databricks.spark.sqldw.JDBCWrapper.$anonfun$executeQueryInterruptibly$1(SqlDWJDBCWrapper.scala:105)
    at com.databricks.spark.sqldw.JDBCWrapper.withPreparedStatement(SqlDWJDBCWrapper.scala:307)
    at com.databricks.spark.sqldw.JDBCWrapper.executeQueryInterruptibly(SqlDWJDBCWrapper.scala:102)
    at com.databricks.spark.sqldw.DefaultSource.$anonfun$validateJdbcConnection$1(DefaultSource.scala:140)
    at com.databricks.spark.sqldw.DefaultSource.$anonfun$validateJdbcConnection$1$adapted(DefaultSource.scala:138)
    at com.databricks.spark.sqldw.JDBCWrapper.withConnection(SqlDWJDBCWrapper.scala:285)
    at com.databricks.spark.sqldw.DefaultSource.validateJdbcConnection(DefaultSource.scala:138)
    at com.databricks.spark.sqldw.DefaultSource.$anonfun$createRelation$3(DefaultSource.scala:88)
    at com.databricks.spark.sqldw.Utils$.wrapExceptions(Utils.scala:410)
    ... 33 more
```

The only changes from earlier to now is that the resource group in which this notebook is running is different from earlier but it is still accessing the data from ADLS in the old resource group. I have tried running dbutils.fs.ls for the old resource group source in the new resource grp notebook and im able to get all the files in ADLS.so connection shouldnt be an issue. I have also changed the databricks runtime back from 8 to 7.3 that was the original.

Below is the conn string format:

```
sqlconnectionstring = "jdbc:sqlserver://"+sqlserver+":1433;database="+sqldatabase+";user="+sqluser+";password="+sqlpassword
```

Pls help me out as i cant seem to find the source of this error at all. I'm using the dedicated pool only. its not on demand. (I checked)

Comment: Connect to your SQL Pool and run `select @@version` it should return `Microsoft Azure SQL Data Warehouse - 10.0.13577.0`.  Not `Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8 `. Does it?

Answer (score 0):

I found i was using datawarehouse format to write to a sql server . changed the format to jdbc in the `df.write.format('jdbc')` it worked. however this format is very slow in writing to the sql server. if there is a faster option some one point it out to me pls